# MapBox 3d buildings styling based on buildings coordinates

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I would like to change buildings colors, knowing buildings addresses/coordinates.
The dataset of buildings is frequently changed.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "knowing buildings addresses/coordinates"? What kind of visualisation are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Also, are you using the buildings layer present in Mapbox Streets, or your own data?